# How to view/redirect to google plus user profile using django-social-auth?

Tags: django, oauth-2.0, google-plus, django-socialauth

Redirects to G+ profiles require "https://plus.google.com/<\profile_id>/posts" format. My problem is that I haven't found the solution on how to get the profile_id dynamically for users of the site. It is not fetched by my current implementation of the django-social-auth (not saved in databases), and the UID field for google-oauth2 accounts records save the google email, maybe if I can find an implementation of how to redirect to a G+ profile using email, it would be fine (though some sources say it is not currently possible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to use the Google+ API to determine the profile ID of a user from their email address.

However, if you're able to send the user through an OAuth 2.0 flow, you can determine their profile ID using the REST API's [people get method](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get). If you're using [Google's API Python client library](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/), the code would look something like this:

```
import apiclient.discovery
import httplib2

flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(
    client_id=client_id,
    client_secret=client_secret,
    scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me',
    user_agent='google-api-client-python-plus-cmdline/1.0',
    xoauth_displayname='Google Plus Client Example App'
    )
credentials_file = 'plus_auth.dat'
storage = Storage(credentials_file)
credentials = run(flow, storage)

http = credentials.authorize(http)
service = apiclient.discovery.build('plus', 'v1', http=http, developerKey=api_key)
people_resource = service.people()    
people_document = people_resource.get(userId='me').execute()

print "ID: " + people_document['id']
```

You can also find a more complete example in the [Google+ Python starter app](http://code.google.com/p/google-plus-python-starter/source/browse/cli/plus_cli.py)

Answer (score 2):

The user id is part of the data sent by google in the OAuth2 workflow, here's how you can store it and then access it:

1. Define this setting:

   GOOGLE_OAUTH2_EXTRA_DATA = [
       ('id', 'id')
   ]
2. Access the id:

   social = user.social_auth.get(provider='google-oauth2')

   profile_id = social.extra_data['id']